# I get this error : [Errno 21] Is a directory:

Tags: python, audio, processing

```py
# Save directory path in 'path'
path = r'---path '

# Declare a dummy Numpy array (row vector)
result_array = np.empty([1,54])

# Create a list of audio file names 'file_list'
file_list = os.listdir(path)

i=0

for filename in file_list:
    
    # Read WAV file. 'rosa.core.load' returns sampling frequency in 'fs' and audio signal in 'sig'
    sig, fs = rosa.core.load(path + '\\' + file_list[i], sr=None)
    
    # Calculate the average mfcc (utterance-level features) using 'rosa.feat.mfcc()' and 'np.mean' method. '.T' transposes the rows and columns. 'axis=0' indicates average is calculated column-wise
    avg_mfcc_feat = np.mean(rosa.feature.mfcc(y=sig, sr=fs, n_mfcc=26).T,axis=0)
    
    # Calculate the standard deviation of mfcc (utterance-level features) using 'rosa.feat.mfcc()' and 'np.std' method. '.T' transposes the rows and columns. 'axis=0' indicates average is calculated column-wise
    std_mfcc_feat = np.std(rosa.feature.mfcc(y=sig, sr=fs, n_mfcc=26).T,axis=0)
    
    # Calculate the average zero crossing rate (utterance-level feature) using 'rosa.feat.zero_crossing_rate()' and 'np.mean' method. '.T' transposes the rows and columns. 'axis=0' indicates average is calculated column-wise
    zcross_feat = rosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(sig)
    avg_zcross_feat = np.mean(rosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(y=sig).T,axis=0)
    
    # Append the three 1D arrays into a single 1D array called 'feat'.
    feat0 = np.append(avg_mfcc_feat, std_mfcc_feat, axis=0)
    
    feat1 = np.append(feat0, avg_zcross_feat, axis=0)
    
    # Save emotion label from file name. 'path' contains directory's address, 'file_list' contains file name, and '\\' joins the two to form file's address
    label = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path + '\\' + file_list[i]))[0].split('-')[2]
    
    # Create a new Numpy array 'sample' to store features along with label
    sample = np.insert(feat1, obj=53, values=label)
    
    result_array = np.append(result_array, sample)
    
    i+=1

# Print out the 1D Numpy array
result_array
```

I'm getting this error while trying to read the contents and loop over the subdirectories of Ravdess dataset. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ? Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) lists the entries of a directory, which are the files *and directories* it contains. If you want to recursively include all files and folders under `path`, then use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

To use only files from `os.listdir()`, then add a check with [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile):

> Return `True` if *path* is an [`existing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) regular file. This follows symbolic links, so both [`islink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink) and [`isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) can be true for the same path.

```py
for filename in file_list:
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)):
        # not a file, skip it
        continue
    # rest of your code here
    sig, fs = rosa.core.load(...)
    ...
```

**2.** Inside the `for`-loop, you've got two cases where you've put `path + '\\' + file_list[i]` - this should be just `path + '\\' + filename`, or better `os.path.join(path, filename)`.

- if you want indexes with the filename iteration, do `for i, filename in enumerate(file_list):` instead of manually incrementing `i`.
- and instead of repeating `os.path.join(path, filename)` multiple times, put it in a variable at the start of your loop:

  ```py
  for filename in file_list:
      filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
      if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
          continue

      sig, fs = rosa.core.load(filepath, sr=None)
      ...
  ```